# Tomcat: External JVM Configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration

I wouldn't ask this here unless I had exhausted the Tomcat reference guide and online searching had produced nadda.

Tomcat has a `bin/catalina.sh` file where you can specify JVM options to start up with. For purposes outside the scope of this question, I'm wondering if Tomcat supports external configuration of these Java options *outside* `catalina.sh`.

Thus, I'd be able to write some file, say, `new-jvm-opts.xml`, and restart Tomcat, and have it use the options set up in this file (overriding any specified in `catalina.sh`).

Comment: There's a `setenv.sh` which catalina.sh can read, and you can set JVM options in there

Comment: fge I'd be happy to give you the green check if you reformatted your comment as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catalina.sh script allows for Environment Variables to be already set on its startup.  If you want to get JVM Opts in there, I think you just set them into whatever Environment your tomcat is starting in.  Its documented in catalina.sh as "Environment Variable Prerequisites".

The ones I think you are interested in are either

```
#   JAVA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
#                   "stop", or "run" command is executed.
#
```

or

```
#   CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
#                   or "run" command is executed. 
#
```

Comment: Thanks Bob but I'm trying to stay out of `catalina.sh`.

Comment: No, no.  You don't modify catalina.sh, you set environment variables outside of it and when catalina.sh runs, it uses them; just like how the PATH environment variable works in the DOS shell or JAVA_HOME.  On  linux/unix you usually set this stuff in ~/.bash_profile or some such.  You can see their values by executing "env".

Answer (score 1):

Use setenv.sh setenv.bat it's in the documentation  - create a file called setenv.[sh/bat] depending on whether your running windows or unix. Add your vm args

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

The setenv file is picked up on startup and applies your vm args, whilst avoiding editing your  catalina.[sh/bat]